# VB.net How to use colordialog?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using colordialog in VB but theres something i can't figure out. My idea was that when i clicked a button the colordialog would open. Then i would pick a color click OK and then i could draw on a picturebox with the color.

My code is:

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e AsSystem.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
Dim mydialog As New ColorDialog
     If (MyDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        If down = True Then
            PictureBox1.CreateGraphics.FillEllipse = mydialog
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But i can't get it to work. Can someone please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to show a dialog on mousemove event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what down is here, but you need to read the color choosen, build a brush with that color, a rect for the size required and finally call FillEllipse on the picturebox area (and don't forget to dispose the Brush)

```
if down = True Then
    If (MyDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
         Dim aBrush = new SolidBrush(mydialog.Color)
         Dim rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
         PictureBox1.CreateGraphics.FillEllipse (aBrush, rect)
         aBrush.Dispose()
     End If
End If
```

As pointed out by Joel Coehoorn in its comment above, this MouseMove event should never be considered for this kind of operation. What are you trying to do with this code inside a MouseMove event?